# How to setup HTTP proxy settings in PHP?

Tags: php, proxy

I am trying to write a program in PHP which I had already written in Java.
I had used the following statements to setup proxy in Java

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost",proxyhost);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort",proxyport);
```

How do I do the same for PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may need to use the cURL extension to carry out the transfer and pass the relevant proxy options to cURL.

[cURL Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

[curl_setopt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) function to pass options to a cURL session

The proxy options you need are: CURL_PROXY and CURL_PROXYPORT.